# DetailsView Item Inserted Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, detailsview

> 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertEventArgs'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'AffectedRows' and no extension method
>   'AffectedRows' accepting a first
>   argument of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewInsertEventArgs'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)...

Comment: please add the code that is giving you this error.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different Events:

1: ItemInserting - has DetailsView***Insert***EventArgs which **does not** contain AffectedRows

2: ItemInserted - has DetailsView***Inserted***EventArgs which **contains** AffectedRows